# Android studio Cannot resolve symbol 'NotificationChannel'

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have updated Android Studio to 3.0 Beta 5

Other classes like NotificationManager are imported just fine. But it's not finding NotificationChannel anywhere.

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
```

What could cause this?

Comment: check your compile sdk pointing to 26?

Comment: On project structure it says 'Compile SDK version: API 23: Android 6.0
Build Tools Version: 26.0.0

Answer (score 7):

NotificationChannel is added in API 26 change your compile SDK to 26 and try

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html

Answer (score 1):

set compileSdkVersion 26 in build.gradle