# Cannot resolve symbol 'NotificationChannel' for Android notifications using FCM

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

I am trying to set up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client app on Android. I am using https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging as a guideline or template for my implementation. When I try to write the code at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MainActivity.java, I see the `Cannot resolve symbol 'NotificationChannel'` error in the following line:

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
```

[image]

Do you have any ideas about why `NotificationChannel` may not be recognized? Thank you.

Comment: What SDK version are you using in your gradle file? It should be 26

Comment: I am using `android:targetSdkVersion="23"`. Is it because I need API Level 26? I am looking at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html and for `NotificationChannel`, it says: `added in API level 26`.

Comment: Target doesn't matter... The compile SDK does

Comment: Where do you define that? This is what I have in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />` Do I need to change the minSdkVersion to 26?

Comment: I found it. I am using `compileSdkVersion 23` in my `build.gradle`. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed, I changed compileSdkVersion from 23 to 26 in my build.gradle file. Thanks @cricket_007. Put this as your answer and I will choose it as the best answer. Thank you.

Comment: Related thread - [Android studio Cannot resolve symbol 'NotificationChannel'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46155562/465053)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NotificationChannel is added in API 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel)

To get this class, the compileSdkVersion needs to be at least that version.

Check the build.gradle

Comment: Hi cricket_007, I am using `compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:24'` in `build.gradle` so can't use `compileSdkVersion 26`. Is there any other solution??

Comment: actually i'm using `com.google.android.maps.`, for this i need to add `compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:24'`

Comment: Again, that class is only available in version 26 and higher, so it would need to be `'Google Inc.:Google APIs:26'`, I guess. Haven't tested though

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be, but your question has nothing to do with Maps https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel

Comment: The problem is, in my project `com.google.android.maps` and `com.google.android.gms.maps` both are implemented. For `com.google.android.maps` I need to use `compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:24'`, because `Google APIs:24` is the latest for map v1, so cannot use `Google APIs:26` or `compileSdkVersion 26` in order to use the NotificationChannel. Please suggest what should I do?

Comment: The Firebase example doesn't use a Google API image. It uses compileSdk 28, so NotificationChannel is available if you just run that code as is... The maps API is separate from the notification channel class... You can use `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0"` for maps and follow along a tutorial from Google site https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup if you want to ask questions about maps, please create a separate post